# Twitter entities no longer recognized in ruby script

Tags: ruby, twitter

I have a ruby script that scans each type of entity in a given tweet:

```
status = Twitter::Client.new.status(tweet[:id_str], {:include_entities => "1"})
status[:entities].each do |x|
  #job on the entity
end
```

It was doing good until yesterday. Now I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'entities' for #<Twitter::Status:0x000001033e1800>`
I can't figure it out since I've checked that `status` does include entities after the first line.
Any clues?

EDIT: turns out it's the new version of the twitter gem (v2.0.0) which is in cause. First I'd like to downgrade it to the last version working (v1.7.2), but I'm getting an annoying gem version error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "hashie":
  In Gemfile:
    topsy (~> 0.3.6) depends on
      hashie (~> 1.0.0)

    twitter (= 1.7.2) depends on
      hashie (1.1.0)
```

How can I work it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was a conflict in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'topsy', '~> 0.3.6'
gem 'twitter', '1.7.2'
```

were requesting different versions of hashie, so I just deleted the version of topsy and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you need specific gem's version, you can forcely set it throught `Gemfile`:

```
gem "rack", "1.0.1"
gem "rails", ">=2.3.2"
```